# java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: permissions not working

Tags: java, android, permissions, sms, android-permissions

I am trying to send a text upon a broadcast of receiving a phone call. Everything is working up until the message is to be sent and it throws this exception.

java.lang.SecurityException: Sending SMS message: uid 10188 does not have android.permission.SEND_SMS.

I realize this is a common issue, but I tried every other posts solutions and none have worked.

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.biapps.makin_biscuits">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".ContactsList">
            <intent-filter>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.ALTERNATIVE" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name=".IncomingCallReceiver"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.Trigger" />

            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32635704/android-permission-doesnt-work-even-if-i-have-declared-it

Comment: Thank you @CommonsWare . I looked through tons of these and never saw that one. Problem solved.